# Writing a subquery by filtering dates

Tags: subquery

I would like to write a query and/or subquery where `Event_Name - Number1` is `< 'date'` and the remaining `event_names` are `> 'date'`. Then populate results based on the `WHERE` clause.

Each `event_name` has an `effective_time` associated with it.

Any ideas?

**I'm interested where queue event is <'date' and all other events are >'date'

Table

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KI0d.png)

```
 Select *      
      Table1.ID
      , sum(CASE WHEN table1.event_name = 'queue' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Name1
      , sum(CASE WHEN table1.event_name = 'cash_settle' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Name2
      , sum(CASE WHEN table.event_name = 'complete_disbursement' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Name3

      from Table1 

     WHERE 
      name3 = '1'
  and name2 = '0'
```

Comment: Table definition and/or sample data might be helpful here.

Comment: Just added. Let me know if thats what you're looking for or if I can provide more info/ data